# Summing columns with same string ID in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, concatenation

I'm sure there's a nice way to do this using pandas, but I keep running in circles.

I want to sum the values in columns that have identical ID numbers.

Example df:

```
ID_number  Billed  Paid  Balance
A100       300     20    280
A100       1000    1000  0
B9B6       1200    0     1200
B9B6       200     40    160
```

What I'm looking for in an output:

```
ID_number  Billed  Paid  Balance
A100       1300    1020  280
B9B6       1400    40    1360
```

The caveat that's been giving me trouble is that the ID numbers contain both letters and numbers.

I've tried splitting the dataframe in two and changing the Billed, Paid, and Balance columns into int values so they can be summed, but I need to group them by the index number in order to sum them together. No matter how I've sliced and diced the dataframes, when I concatenate them together again, it comes back as the 'object' type and my object numbers get smashed together like strings instead of added together like int values should.

I also tried changing individual column datatypes, but I couldn't get that to work because some of the numbers are quite long decimal-wise, and I was returned this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

I've been attempting to use the `df.groupby(['ID_number'].agg('sum')` function for my aggregation.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: df.groupby('ID_number').sum()?

Comment: @BEN_YO when I use this, the row output ends up as 'A100 3001000 201000 2800', as if the objects are joined instead of being summed.

Comment: Your column type is string, convert them to numeric and @BEN_YO solution will work.

Comment: @Erfan when I change column type to string using df['ID_number'] = df['ID_number'].astype(int) , I get the following error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7.140000000000001'

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df.groupby('ID_number').sum()
```

Comment: @BEN_YO suggested this above, but whenever I do, the row output ends up as 'A100 3001000 201000 2800', as if the objects are joined instead of being summed.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Please post these rows before the grouping

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
 df.groupby(['ID_number']).sum()
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Now I've seen you don't have an index column, try this:

```
index_list = pd.Index.tolist(df.ID_number)
```

Try this one:

```
index_list = pd.Index.tolist(df.index)
df.groupby(index_list).sum()
```

It turns the index column to a list, then uses it in the groupby function.
Hope this solves your problem.